# CSS flexbox - is there a better way to do this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The result I'm looking for is one big block on the left, and then four small blocks on the right, and everything aligns. 
I managed to do this [**in this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mk4t8xhp/1/) but my solution has a couple of problems: 
- it's not very clean in terms of code

- it's not responsive 

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box big">ONE</div>
  <div class="med-wrapper">
    <div class="row-1">
      <div class="box medium">TWO</div>
      <div class="box medium">THREE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-2">
      <div class="box medium">FOUR</div>
      <div class="box medium">FIVE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 200px;
}
  /* @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: column
  } */

.box {
  background: #09f;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.big {
  flex: 5;
}

.medium {
  flex: 5;
  height: 100px;
}

.med-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Also, you might notice that I have set the `flex` on both `.big` and `.medium` to 5, because I want the total width of the big box and the total width of two medium boxes to be equal, but it didn't work.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a framework like [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) that has these built in?

Comment: Thank you for not using Bootstrap.

Comment: To do this with Bootstrap is [a lot more complicated](http://jsfiddle.net/3krz2k9y/), at least in my opinion. Besides, I don't really like Bootstrap, I feel like I don't have a lot of control over it.

Comment: Anyways, something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/mk4t8xhp/4/)? Assuming you want rows to be rows. Wrapping doesn’t quite work, though; you’ll have to set some minimums.

Comment: @minitech This looks much better, thanks. However, I was wondering - can this be done with less markup?

Comment: It can always be done with less markup. Something that comes to mind, for example, is a completely flat structure with absolute positioning for each `id`. That’s probably not appropriate for your situation, though, so pick markup that represents your content, then add the minimum number of wrappers to make it work. In the case of that precise layout, without having knowledge of/restrictions on the content, that may well be the minimum.

Comment: Anyway, you should make this into an answer. And do you have an idea about responsiveness?

Comment: minitech's solution is elegant and I believe solves the layout issue you had, however I have a suggestion for the responsiveness, simply assigning a flex-direction: column to the wrapper and rows in a media query could be useful like so - http://jsfiddle.net/mk4t8xhp/7/ I have set the query to trigger at 600px for demonstration purposes, resize the output to see it in action.

Comment: @Vishu Cool, thanks. Does anybody have a suggestion for a better name instead of `med-wrapper`? It's not so semantic, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to have everything to align without getting into a lot of constraints, but using flexbox wrapping in the column direction on the right part could work.

Here's a quick version that uses a `flex-flow: column wrap` on the right part (`.med-wrapper`) and gets rid of the wrapper element on the two column wrappers inside it -

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box big">
    ONE
  </div>

  <div class="med-wrapper">
    <div class="box medium">TWO</div>
    <div class="box medium">THREE</div>
    <div class="box medium">FOUR</div>
    <div class="box medium">FIVE</div>
  </div><!-- /.med-wrapper -->

</div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

...and then the CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'calibri', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 200px;
}


.box {
  background: #09f;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.med-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
}

.medium {
  /* exact sizing for the medium boxes (i.e. get it from main sizing.) */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* adjust for margins: */
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: calc(50% - 5px);
}



/* some theoretical adjustments for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* switch the wrapper to column dir, and remove fixed height. */
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* just a min height for demo purposes. */
  .big {
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  /* Now we need to re-set a height on this one, if we
  want to keep the 2x2 square thing. */
  .med-wrapper {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 200px;
  }
 }
```

Live demo at http://jsbin.com/kasez/5/edit

I've used `calc()`for the size calculations to counter margins, but hey, if you're already depending on flexbox, you probably need a fallback anyway. :-)

It should work with just the one explicit height on the `.wrapper` element, but the rest of the items should adjust accordingly - the downside is that overflow handling gets hard.

This is, incidentally, the type of "2D" situation (vs flexbox's 1D) that Grid Layout is meant to help with, but it'll be a while before that is a viable option.